# Access Customer Attributes from Generic Inquiry

Tags: sql, attributes, acumatica

I need to leverage [Customer Attributes](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(6))/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=9ac91432-d70f-4f00-bc0a-f5569d76cdfd) in a [Generic Inquiry](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(7))/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=38b047fd-a5b8-4a0f-90b2-2ca76535ff1d). I devise most of my Generic Inquiries starting with raw SQL in Server Management Studio. I find it much easier to locate the data I need this way. However, I am having a terrible time figuring out how Attributes are tied to Customers. Attributes are added to a [Customer Class](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(4))/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=9c074949-cc36-4a7c-a70f-506f04828251), and then a customer is associated with a Customer Class. This allows any attributes available for that Customer Class to be modifiable for the Customer.

Using the database, I have found the following:

- Individual Attribute objects are stored in the `CSAttribute` table
- Options for the Attributes (such as combobox) are stored in the `CSAttributeDetail` table
- Individual instances of each attribute are stored in the `CSAnswers` table
- There is also a `CSAttributeGroup` table, which I believe relates `CSAttributeDetail` records to `CSAttribute` records.

So, one would expect the `CSAnswers` table to have a reference to the customer the answer is attached to... but it does not. This table is defined as:

- CompanyID (PK, int, not null)
- RefNoteID (PK, uniqueidentifier, not null)
- AttributeID (PK, nvarchar(10), not null)
- Value (nvarchar(255), null)

To add insult to injury, table names in the database do not always align 1-to-1 to what is available in a Generic Inquiry. For example, many fields that are available to `ARInvoice` in a GI are actually stored in the `ARRegister` table in the database. I suspect something very similar is going on for Attributes.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of locating how Attributes are associated to Customers at both the database level, and at the GI level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a number of GIs using Customer Attributes, the RefNoteID uniqueidentifier in the CSAnswers table relates to the NoteID uniqueidentifier on the Customer table, and the AttributeID is the specific Attribute. To get All attributes for a customer on multiple Rows join on just the RefNoteID, if you want specific attribute(s) add additional join conditions for each AttributeID. [image]

Comment: I assumed the refNoteID was a reference to the notes you can add all over the system. When attempting to implement this in SQL it frustrates me to find the `Customers` table does not have a `noteID` column... I will spend some time searching for a connection to use with a noteID. Thanks for the input. I'll mark as answer once I get it working as a GI.

Answer (score 4):

Attributes are linked to the record with the RefNoteID field; it will match the NoteID of the other record (note that in your case it wouldn't be in the Customers table but in BAccount, which is a 1:1 join with Customers). You should rarely, if ever, need to directly reference the CSAnswers table. Internally, Acumatica will generate a set of virtual fields in the primary table that match the name of the attribute, suffixed with _Attributes:

[image: Attributes fields for BAccount table]

Please note that you won't be able to reference the attribute in the "Conditions" tab, however you can filter by this column in the grid and create predefined filters.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the `noteID` is on the `BAccount` table. I was able to successfully build my SQL to satisfaction once I made that connection. I would argue against "You should rarely, if ever, need to directly reference the CSAnswers table." When using the pre-populated Attribute fields in the GI the system generates a warning and suggests to add the join to the tables/relations for performance gains.

Comment: The warning is just a generic warning for fields that issue subselects, but I can guarantee that attributes have been specifically optimized  and tested and to work in inquiries with hundreds of thousands of rows and dozens of attributes.